# How to use debugger in android or Java?

Tags: java, android, windows, debugging

I am trying to create a simple android application. This is the first time I am coding for android and Java. I have installed android sdk on win 7 machine. I have never used a debugger. I want a resource to learn use of debugger in android from basic. If it is same as Java, Kindly provide me a link to learn java debugger from basic. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you are using eclipse to develop an Android app. If not the please do that.

Here is a information to [debug an Android app](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/index.html).

Comment: Yes, I am using eclipse. Thanks for the link but it provide very high overview of debugging. I want to learn from basic.

Comment: its from basics it self, what specific things you want to learn? Just debug your project, put break point, watcher and use DDMS... Eclipse is very user friendly i dont see any specific need to read to Debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just playing around with the Eclipse debugger?

Try:

1. Click on the left-hand margin next to code you want to investigate, setting a "breakpoint"
2. Click on the bug icon to run your application in Debug mode.
3. When your application arrives at that line of code, Eclipse will pop up a dialog confirming a change to the debug perspective.
4. Play with the step-next/step-out buttons in the debugger.